# How do I use IHttpClientFactory with .NET Core 5.x and Blazor given that there is not a normal class structure in a .RAZOR file?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, .net-5, ihttpclientfactory

I would like to preface this post with the fact that I am VERY new to C#, .NET Core, and Blazor after being a long-time Java person.

I am following along with Microsoft's documentation on **[Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0)**, but I cannot seem to understand how to use this with my application.

I have a IP address for an API endpoint, So I created a Named Client:

```
services.AddHttpClient("TheAPIEndpoint", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("192.168.1.234");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Skynet v1.0");
});
```

Next, I went to the "Basic Usage" section of the documentation at the top of the page where it says:

*An IHttpClientFactory can be requested using dependency injection (DI). The following code uses IHttpClientFactory to create an HttpClient instance*

It says to create a constructor for my class and pass in an IHttpClientFactory:

```
public class BasicUsageModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public BasicUsageModel(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
    }
}
```

Here is where my issue "begins". When you create a new Razor component for a Blazor application, the generated .RAZOR file looks like this:

```
<h3>HelloWorld</h3>

@code {

}
```

When I need to call the API, I need to create this method:

```
private async Task GetSearchResults()
{
    // ...
}
```

All together, it looks like this:

```
<h3>HelloWorld</h3>
@if (fetchedResults != null)
{
    @foreach (var result in fetchedResults)
    {
        <p>@(result.someData)</p>
    }
}

@code {
    private async Task GetSearchResults()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://192.168.1.234:8082/");
        // ...
        fetchedResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultSet>(response);
    }
}
```

As you see, I don't have a "normal" class structure in which to create the constructor, to which to pass an `IHttpClientFactory` parameter, with which I can create a new HttpClient.

So, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blazor does not support constructors as you've already discovered, [instead it provides the `@inject` directive to support dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server). The syntax is:

```blazor
@inject <dependency-type-name> <variable-name>
```

In your case:

```blazor
@inject IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory
<h3>HelloWorld</h3>
@if (fetchedResults != null)
{
    @foreach (var result in fetchedResults)
    {
        <p>@(result.someData)</p>
    }
}

@code {
    private async Task GetSearchResults()
    {
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://192.168.1.234:8082/");
        // ...
        fetchedResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultSet>(response);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register your dependencies in the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method!

Comment: That was it ... thank you! I feel like I am NEVER going to get the hang of this. Have a great day!